# Arc fault breakers and Subzero refrigerators

Tags: electrical

I have two Subzero refrigerators. Both are on dedicated circuits. Subzero recommends a 15 amp breaker. Each refrigerators is on a 20 amp arc fault breaker. They tripped the breakers 4 or 5 times each.

City code requires an arc fault on the refrigerator. The manufacturer says the units are not designed for a arc fault.  Mfg had a technician test the arc fault with a 14 amp vacuum cleaner. The test was to run the vacuum for a minute (*5 times*) to see if it kicks the breaker. Both breakers proved to be OK, no trip.

Mfg recommended replacing the breaker with new A/F breakers and again said the units were not compatible with the A/F.  They said their new machines are being designed around the A/F but the 2020 was not.

The A/F is to protect the user not the machine right?

Comment: It would help if you let us know what city you're in. Putting refrigerators on arc fault breakers is stupid. It's possible your city code is stupid -- stranger things have happened. But it's also possible your inspector (or whoever quoted the code to you) was misinformed, which is probably a lot more common.

Comment: What year was your home built? @harpers advice is good and with sub zero they are designed for built in and direct wiring but if prior to 2014 arc fault protection was not required unless a local mandate. I have found where customers have installed them then wanted them removed because of this exact issue, but I am surprised they are failing being new units.

Comment: What make and model are the breakers in question?  Also...*wow*...is it really taking folks that long to not spew a bunch of AFCI-confusing hash down the powerline?

Comment: @threephaseeel , I still get calls on brand new devices that trip arc faults, including simple dimmers and switching supplies washing machines. AFCI’s can not tell when electronic control is harmonic or an arc, they used to be worse and are getting better but I have seen this several times a year and it has been a failure to properly detect what is a fault and a harmonic, especially on circuits that are above 50% loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The arc-fault breaker protects the **wiring** from an electrical fire caused by arcing.

Arc-fault detection has absolutely nothing to do with ground-fault detection.  The only similarity is the 4-letter acronym.

Change the wiring method to EMT, IMC or Rigid metal conduit (EMT is by far the easier to work with).  If the run from panel to first outlet is in one of those conduits, then Code only requires arc-fault breakers at the first receptacle.

So make the runs **dedicated** runs that power only that freezer, which are in EMT conduit.  Then, skip the receptacle and hardwire the refrigerators.

Comment: to answer some of the questions, the breaker is a 20 amp square D Type QO120CAFI, 10kA 120V- As mentioned, they are dedicated lines to each refrigerator. On the next house, i would consider the EMT or IMC but theis one is finished and would require major tear out to accomplish. House is located in Galveston, Texas. Since the receptacles are behind the built in Subs (72" combined across) It requires techs to remove the units and would take too long to restore power. Thanks for everyones review and consideration.

Comment: @MRoll Then it's time to talk to your AHJ about a variance on the arc-fault requirements.  Arc-fault breakers are a blanket requirement they just slap on almost every circuit, in hopes of reducing arc-fault fires on average.  **Dedicated circuits to sockets rarely disturbed** are the least likely to actually gain benefit from AFCI. (Remember, that bolded text was, 1966 to 1996, the justification for allowing *ungrounded, bootlegged* dryer and range connections!)

Comment: @MRoll -- can you try turning off one of the breakers in question, then turning it back on while holding down the TEST button and using a stopwatch to time it until it trips again, then tell us how long it took to trip? (Or in other words, we're asking you to use the [trip diagnostics on your breaker](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/43/43a955a6-2154-4899-9aee-a70a4c2308c3.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got tired of worring about loosing a refrig of food i installed a regular breakers. We got by with reg breakers for the prior 50 years without burning the house down. I was told that an arc fault will develop a memory. After it trips X number of times, it learns the load and calibrates to accomidate the appliance. I was then told square D does not have that feature. I asked Subzero to send me a note suggesting i install a regular breaker and they declined.